# How to persist data to Hive from PySpark - Avoiding duplicates

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am working with `graphframes`, `pyspark`, and `hive` to work with graph data. As I process data I will be building a graph and eventually will be persisting this data into a Hive table, where I will not update it ever again.

Subsequent runs may have relationships to nodes from previous runs, so I will want to ensure I don't duplicate data.

For example, run #1 might find nodes: `A`, `B`, `C`. Run #2 might re-find node `A`, and also find new nodes `X`, `Y`, `Z`. I do not want `A` to appear twice in my table.

I am looking for the best way to handle this and would like to address the following issues:

1. I will need to track the status of the node as I process metadata associated with it. I will **only** want to persist the node's data to Hive after I have finished this processing.
2. I want to ensure that I don't create duplicate data when I encounter the same node (e.g. when I re-find `A` node above, I don't want to insert another row into Hive)

I am currently tinkering with the best way to do this. I know `hive` supports ACID transactions now, but it does not appear as though `pyspark` currently supports CRUD type operations. So here is what I'm planning on:

1. On each run, create a `dataframe` to store the nodes I have found.
2. When a new node is found: Check if the node already exists in Hive (e.g. `sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM existingTable WHERE name="<NAME>")`. If it does not exist update the `dataframe` with `x = vertices.withColumn("name", F.when(F.col("id")=="a", "<THE-NEW-NAME>").otherwise(F.col("name")))` to add it to our Dataframe.
3. Once all the nodes have finished processing, create a temporary view: `x.createOrReplaceTempView("myTmpView")`
4. Finally, insert data from my temporary view into an existing table with `sqlContext.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE existingTable SELECT * FROM myTmpView")`

I think this will work, but it seems extremely hacky. I'm not sure if this is a function of my lack of understanding of Hive/Spark, or if this is just the nature of the tech stack. Is there a better way to do this? Is there a performance cost to handling it in this way?

Answer (score 0):

In deltalake api, upserts(Merge) are supported using scala and also python. Which is exactly you are trying to implement.

https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#merge-examples

Here is an alternate solution

1. Have a column updated_time timestamp in your table
2. union prev_run_results and current_run_results
3. group by 'node', select the latest timestamp
4. save the results

Comment: With the proposed alternate solution, wouldn't this read all of the data before writing it back out? This seems undesirable if the data is extremely large?

Comment: yes, it is read efficient way, if you want write efficient, write duplicates and later while reading get only the latest one (using step 3).